# Add print file button to pdf created using iText

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to add "print file" button to a dynamically created pdf file. I am not even sure whether its possible or where to start.

EDIT:

I have this one solution using Javascript from this [link](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=154). But some PDF Readers dont allow Javascript by default.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about readers that don't "allow javascript". If they do that, half of the internet will be broken for them, and it's only their own fault.

Comment: @MightyPork, I agree. But, some pdf Readers dont allow javascript to run by default and at times its not that easy to change the settings.

Comment: If the PDF is dynamically generated, what's the point of a "print button"? Just redirect the user to the pdf file, and they can print it in their pdf viewer. Besides, you tagged it "ajav" and you're talking "javascript". Not really sure you know whatcha doing.

Comment: its created using java for a desktop application and its the client requirement to have pdf button on pdf.

Comment: I dint tag ajax or javascript. May be a confusion.

Comment: is it even possible to have javascript inside pdf? That sounds just wrong!

Comment: Yes, its possible. See the link in edit which shows how to do it.

Comment: I hope you realize that it's some non-standard feature that works probably only in the Adobe-made proprietary viewer?

Comment: I dint know that. Thanks for the info. It was working in adobe and foxit. But I dint like solution anyway and is still waiting for a proper solution.

Comment: Printing is done by adding a Javascript action to a button, but not all PDF viewers support Javascript. For those viewers, there's no solution. For the others, see: [Print PDF Created using itextsharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751910/print-pdf-created-using-itextsharp)